# can i let the field in the html to have a specific layout when this value is not the default values

Tags: python, html, django

i made some fields useing Django as `models.CharField` and set the default values to `default="-"`

i also made the html tamplat to show the fields. so can i let the field in the html to have a specific layout or text effect when this value is not the default values `default="-"`

modeks.py

```
Iron_Fe = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="-", blank=True, null=True)
Carbon_C = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="-", blank=True, null=True)
```

html

```
<td id="Fe" title="Iron"><sup>{{ object.Iron_Fe }}</sup>Fe</td>
<td id="C" title="Carbon"><sup>{{ object.Carbon_C }}</sup>C</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use if template tags like following:

```
<td style="{% if object.Iron_Fe != '-' %} background-color: lightgreen; {% endif %}" 
    id="Fe" title="Iron"><sup>{{ object.Iron_Fe }}</sup>Fe
</td>
```

That will change background color of column to lightgreen if the value is not "-" otherwise it will do nothing.

Comment: there's some erorr in it the vs code is showing me a red signal in this line

Comment: What is the error can you type it here ? Just copy paste style attribute to both the td tags respectively.

Comment: i upload  the image erorr in vsc in here: https://ibb.co/NCs07rf

Comment: Hover on the red line and send me error message. And have you ran the code ?

Comment: i didnt run it yet

Comment: ok its working, but it dosent make sense, why in vsc showing me a red line tho

Comment: It could be vs code doesn't have django plugin installed.

Comment: im wondering now when the default values is "-", can i hied that field comoletely
html: <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left">Copper - Cu</td>
                <td>{{ object.Copper_Cu }}</td>
            </tr>

Comment: @ZakMeshou I don't understand

Comment: when the default values is "-", can we hied that field comoletely

Comment: You need this `<tr> <td style="visibility: hidden">Copper - Cu</td> <td>{{ object.Copper_Cu }}</td> </tr>`. Also, it was a pleasure to help you despite that you ignored my answer below, which was posted earlier :)

Comment: @Zak Meshou for that you have to post a different question.